# Remove filter and view options from custom post type edit screen

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, columns

I have my CPT edit screen almost looking how I want it but want to remove the filter and view options from this screen as they are not needed for this interface. How do I remove them? Are there any filters that disable them?

[image: How my CPT edit screen looks now]

My edit screen has got to this stage by this code so far:

```
// Manage columns in edit screen
add_filter('manage_edit-staff_columns', 'sc_staff_modify_columns');
function sc_staff_modify_columns($staff_columns) {
    $staff_columns['title'] = __('Staff Name', 'sc_wilsons_custom');
    $staff_columns['job_role'] = __('Job Role', 'sc_wilsons_custom');
    $staff_columns['is_store_manager'] = __('Store Manager', 'sc_wilsons_custom');
    $staff_columns['located'] = __('Located At', 'sc_wilsons_custom');
    unset($staff_columns['date']);
    return $staff_columns;
}
add_action('manage_staff_posts_custom_column', 'sc_staff_manage_columns', 10, 2);
function sc_staff_manage_columns($column_name, $id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $custom = get_post_custom($id);
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'job_role':
            echo $custom["sc_staff_job_role"][0];
        break;

        case 'is_store_manager':
            echo ($custom["sc_staff_store_manager"][0] == 1) ? __('Yes', 'sc_wilsons_custom') : __('No', 'sc_wilsons_custom');
        break;

        case 'located':
            if(is_int($custom["sc_staff_located"][0])){
                $post = get_post($custom["sc_staff_located"][0]);
                echo $post->post_title;
            } else {
                _e('Unknown', 'sc_wilsons_custom');
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

*EDIT:* if it helps I have found where the code for these bits are generated. Functions `months_dropdown()` and `view_switcher` in file /wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php

I don't see any filters or hooks here so might be out of luck. Anyway of doing this by extending the WP_List_Table class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css:

```
.tablenav.top .alignleft.actions select[name="m"],
.tablenav.top .alignleft.actions select#cat,
.tablenav.top .alignleft.actions input#post-query-submit,
.tablenav.top .view-switch { 
    display: none; 
}
```

*Note: You'll have to take a look at the input elements ID. I guess this will be named different on custom post types.*

Comment: Sorry kaiser I cannot see any element ID's that have my post type in that I can capture these elements just on this CPT.

Comment: @Brady check post_type in GET and conditionally insert the css if it matches.

Comment: @Milo - Messy but ok I'll look into